# Why doesn't ExtendScript throw an error on invalid XML string?

Tags: xml, extendscript

I'm now developing a bit with XML and ExtendScript.  I'm not sure I understand why, when I run the following script, the ESTK does NOT throw an error:

```
var random_string = "asdsfjlkj";

try {
  testXML = new XML(random_string);
} catch (err) {
  $.writeln("There was an error creating an XML object:" + err);
}
```

I would expect the `$.writeln` string to show up in ESTK's console, but it doesn't.  Instead I just get `Result: undefined`.  According to Adobe's Javascript Tools Guide on page 246 :

> If a valid string is supplied, returns a new XML object encapsulating the XML code. If the XML code cannot be parsed, throws a JavaScript error.
>    If an existing object is supplied and the new operator is used, returns a copy of the object; otherwise, returns the object itself.

I guess my question is what kind of string would the `new XML()` method actually throw an error?

Comment: What happens when you remove the try catch statement?

Comment: First you have extra `)` in the `new XML` line. Second, the XML constructor can get a string, but if you try to write `new XML('<asdf');` you will get an Error.

Comment: confirmed what @Ziki wrote. It is again one of the quirks of Extendscript

Comment: @Ziki I updated the code so the extra paren is removed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `x = new XML (y);` is to create a new object `x` of type XML, with an initial value of `y`, where `y` must form a string representation of *valid* XML.

From the ESTK Help:

> XML **XML** (text: *string*)
>   Parses an XML string. Throws an error if the XML is incorrect.

Thus, the following will all fail:

Ziki's `<asdf`: "There was an error creating an XML object:SyntaxError: XML error in line 1 - Unclosed token"

`<abc a='1>`: ".. - Unclosed token"

`<abc a=1>`: ".. - Not well-formed (invalid token)"

`<123>`: ".. - Not well-formed (invalid token)"

`<abcd><b></abcd>`: ".. - Mismatched tag"

`<?xml verson="1.0"?><abc>`: ".. - Syntax error" (Here, `verson` needs to be `version`)

And these (each line is a separate input string) are okay:

```
abcd>
<abcd>
<abcd><a> (this automatically gets expanded to <abcd><a/></abcd>)
<abc a="1">
```

Comment: Thanks @Jongware for the clarification.  Adobe should add this to their documentation :)